# Using firebase to get users list that navigate to a specific screen

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-analytics

I am new to firebase and React Native.

Is there any way in firebase that I can get the list of users with my required data(i.e phone number) or any other data that I may send from the App to the firebase when the users navigate to a specific screen in the App.

Currently, I can see Analytics -> Events -> Screen Name and then there is engagement time. Can I pass and get there my required data i.e users id or anything that I will pass. If yes, How can I achieve this ? Or is there anything else I need to do for this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no Firebase API to *get* analytics data from Analytics into your application code.

If you want your app to show a list of users, the common way is to store that list of users in a cloud-hosted database (such as Firestore or the Realtime Database that are also part of Firebase), and then read it from there into your app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 1 more thing, is firebase providing the data like user snapshot data in any other tab/place ? Because it is realtime and disappears from there after some time. What if I need all the users data afterwards ? From where can I get it ?

Comment: Sorry, I am having a real hard time parsing what you're saying there. Keep in mind that Firebase has 18 or so products, and many of them may have the concept of a user. But Analytics does not expose a user object anywhere that I know of.

Comment: I am referring to Analytics->dashboard->real time-> user snapshot. It provides a complete detail of how the app user interacted with the screens of any app.

Comment: That information is only available within the Google Analytics UI. It is not available though an API, nor in the data stream that you can export to BigQuery.